# Can't get the SATO CL4NX printer to accept (versus print) commands

Tags: c#, printing

I'm writing a WinForm application that's supposed to send a series of commands to the SATO CL4NX label printer. I'm using Visual Studio 2013, C# and I'm using the USB port to print`enter code here`. The result of my efforts is that the printer just prints the TEXT of the commands.

For example I'm sending the following string:

```
"<STX><ESC>AH0050<ESC>V0100<ESC>L0303<ESC>B<ESC>XMSATO<ESC>Z<ETX>"
```

What is printed is:

```
"<STX><ESC>AH0050<ESC>V0100<ESC>L0303<ESC>B<ESC>XMSATO<ESC>Z<ETX>"
```

My code is as follows:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.AppendLine("<STX><ESC>A");
            sb.AppendLine("H0050<ESC>V0100<ESC>L0303<ESC>B<ESC>XMSATO<ESC>Z<ETX>");
            String output = sb.ToString().Replace("<ESC>", "\x1B");
            output = output.Replace("<STX>", ((char)2).ToString());
            output = output.Replace("<ETX>", ((char)3).ToString());
            yPos = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
            ev.Graphics.DrawString(output, printFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
```

The actual string that's sent to the printer is:

```
\r\nA\r\nH0050V0100L0303BXMSATOZ\r\n
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Steve

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is SATO printer command uses ESC character which is '1B' in hexiadecimal. You actually don't need to send STX and ETX characters.
Also, you may want to specify Q command for number of label to be printed:

```
[1Bh]A
 [1Bh]H0050
 [1Bh]V0100
 [1Bh]L0303[1Bh]B[1Bh]XMSATO
 [1Bh]Q1
[1Bh]Z
```